# Local Machine appsettings.json file not overwriting in production env

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, appsettings

Local Machine appsettings.json file not overwriting in production environment, in production environment its taking below setting, needed some guidance on how to avoid the below setting in production environment.

```
 "AppSettings": {
        "JobRequired": false,
        "PortalPath": "https://example.com",
        "EmailAddress": "xyz@example.com",
        "ABCPortalUrl": "https://localhost:44000",
        "Environment": "DEV",
        "KeyVaultDisabled": true,
    },
```

Comment: In the properties for `appsettings.json` what is `Copy to Output Directory` set to? It should be `Copy if newer` most likely.

Comment: You can always override them using [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is .NET Core/5, you have to create an additional appsettings.json for the specific environments. For example, Production would have an appsettings.production.json file defined in your project.

This file would have your production specific settings and would take precedence over the original appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the appsettings.json file for configuring your application. Configuration in ASP.NET Core is performed using one or more configuration providers. Configuration providers read configuration data from key-value pairs using a variety of configuration sources:

1. Settings files, such as appsettings.json
2. Environment variables
3. Azure Key Vault
4. Azure App Configuration
5. Command-line arguments
6. Custom providers installed or created
7. Directory files
8. In-memory .NET objects

Here is the article for [setting configuration and how to use your code based on the configuration set in the appsettings.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cp)